# How to detect the mouse wheel button is pressed down in .NET program?

Tags: .net, winforms, mouseevent

I would like to detect the mouse wheel button is pressed down in order to implement the 'panning' behavior (as used in AutoCAD) in a VB.NEt program, how can I achieve this?

I've tries to put the code under:

Form1_MouseWheel, Form1_MouseClick eventhandlers:

```
If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Middle Then
  Dim a = 11
End If
```

but the break point set on the line "Dim a=11" never got hit.

Comment: Code works for the MouseDown or MouseClick events.  Make sure you don't have a control in that area of the form.

Comment: Set your break on the IF and see what value e.Button contains - assumes MouseClick is even fired.

Comment: @LarsTech is correct, however there is this CAD control on the form which seems to be capturing the mouse click events, but since it is an old ActiveX control, its mouseclick eventhandler doesn't capture the wheelmouse down, only left button, right button.